# How do I keep component state in React during Route changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a fairly simple shopping app (the Odin Project Shopping Cart project) using react-router-dom.  I am keeping the contents of the shopping cart in App component state, but when a new route is rendered, the component state is lost.  How do I get the state to persist across route changes?

My App.js looks like this:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./style.scss";
import Items from "./components/Items.js";
import Home from "./components/Home.js";
import Nav from "./components/Nav.js";
import Cart from "./components/Cart.js";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numItemsInCart: 0,
      itemsInCart: {},
      totalPrice: 0,
    };
  }

  addToCart = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const target = event.target.parentNode;
    const { vin, price } = target.dataset;
    const number = parseInt(target.quantity.value);

    this.setState({ numItemsInCart: this.state.numItemsInCart + number });

    if (this.state.itemsInCart.hasOwnProperty(vin)) {
      this.setState({
        itemsInCart: {
          ...this.state.itemsInCart,
          [vin]: this.state.itemsInCart[vin] + number,
        },
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        itemsInCart: { ...this.state.itemsInCart, [vin]: number },
      });
    }
    this.setState({
      totalPrice: this.state.totalPrice + parseFloat(price) * number,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav
          numItemsInCart={this.state.numItemsInCart}
          totalPrice={this.state.totalPrice}
          className="nav"
        />
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/items">
              <Items addToCart={this.addToCart} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path="/cart">
              <Cart />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

...and the github repo is [here.](https://github.com/JonathanDPotter/shopping-cart)

The `Nav.js` is below:

```js
const Nav = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="nav">
      <ul className="nav-ul">
        <Router forceRefresh={true}>
          <Link to="/">
            <li className="link">Home</li>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/items">
            <li className="link">Shop</li>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/cart">
            <li className="link">
              <span className="total-items">{props.numItemsInCart}</span>
              <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
              <span className="total-price">${props.totalPrice}</span>
            </li>
          </Link>
        </Router>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the prop `forceRefresh` in the `Nav`'s `Router`, which as the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter/forcerefresh-bool) says, will imitate a traditional page navigation and *use full page refreshes on page navigation*.

By using a full page refresh, you are undoing one of the most important reasons to use a SPA in the first place. You could just remove the prop, but I'm guessing you added this to fix another issue.

The main problem is that you're using two separate `Router`s. One in `App` and one in `Nav`. There are very very few good use-cases for using more than one `Router` in the same React app.

Now I'm guessing you're using the second `Router` in `Nav` because the `Link` was not working correctly. This is because `Link` needs to be a child of `Router` in order to work.

So finally, the full solution is to lift the `Router` up so that both the `Nav` and your `Route`'s are children of the `Router`.

```js
<div>
  <Router>
    <Nav
      numItemsInCart={this.state.numItemsInCart}
      totalPrice={this.state.totalPrice}
      className="nav"
    />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/items">
        <Items addToCart={this.addToCart} />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/cart">
        <Cart />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```